# Java 8 stream variable used in lambda should be final or effectively final

Tags: java, variables, java-8, java-stream, final

This question is already asked. But today I found something odd. For the following code:-

```
public static List<EsbBucketInstanceDefinition> convertBucketDefinitionList(List<BucketInstanceDefinitionV1> bucketInstanceDefinitionV1List) {
    List<EsbBucketInstanceDefinition> response = new ArrayList<>();
    List<EsbBucketInstanceDefinition> finalResponse = new ArrayList<>();
    bucketInstanceDefinitionV1List.stream().forEach(e -> {
        EsbBucketInstanceDefinition esbBucketInstanceDefinition = new EsbBucketInstanceDefinition();
        esbBucketInstanceDefinition.setInstanceType(e.getInstanceType());
        esbBucketInstanceDefinition.setReportingGroup(e.getReportingGroup());
        esbBucketInstanceDefinition.setSliceVolume(e.getSliceVolume());
        esbBucketInstanceDefinition.setCounterName(e.getCounterName());
        esbBucketInstanceDefinition.setSubscriberGroupId(e.getSubscriberGroupId());
        // response.add(esbBucketInstanceDefinition); compiler error variable used in lambda should be final or effective final 
        finalResponse.add(esbBucketInstanceDefinition);
    });
    return finalResponse;
}
```

For this works fine. Looks like only variable name finalResponse is working. How and why? Is it valid to do?

Comment: you are not modifying the reference itself, but adding to an `ArrayList` - this will work, but it is discouraged...

Comment: also notice that in your case, you do not need `stream` at all; `List::forEach` exists

Comment: Can u pls why is it discouraged? Pls, explain more. What is the recommended way?

Comment: the recommended way it to do a `map(....).collect(Collectors.toList())`. search the documentation for side-effects

Comment: You could possibly improve your code creating a constructor in `EsbBucketInstanceDefinition` and using `map` in streams with `collect` as: `public static List<EsbBucketInstanceDefinition> convertBucketDefinitionList(List<BucketInstanceDefinitionV1> bucketInstanceDefinitionV1List) { return bucketInstanceDefinitionV1List.stream() .map(e -> new EsbBucketInstanceDefinition(e.getInstanceType(), e.getReportingGroup(), e.getSliceVolume(), e.getCounterName(), e.getSubscriberGroupId())) .collect(Collectors.toList()); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References may only be made to (effectively) final variables from within a lambda.

The reference held by `finalResponse` in effectively final, because it never changes. Note that changing the reference means assigning a new value to it, eg

```
finalResponse = someOtherList;
```

Changing the *state* of the object referred to (eg adding items to the list referred to by `finalResponse`) is irrelevant to what the value held by the variable `finalResponse`, ie

```
finalResponse.add(something);
```

Does not change the variable `finalResponse`; it only changes the object to which `finalResponse` refers.

Comment: If this is the question to be inferred, how about closing [this as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238974/java-8-steam-variable-used-in-lambda-should-be-final-or-effective-final#comment95305866_54238974)? Since this doesn't still relate then to the commented out code in the question. At least, the suggestion using `map` and `collect` could have solved the problem by not making use of the lambda here at all.