# Using inner Lambda expression is causing exception

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am really confused while using Lambda expression in my code. I have declared a variable outside of the lambda expression and while using it inside the lambda expression, I am getting exception as:

```
Local variable var1 defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
```

Below is my code:

```java
String var1=null;
String var2;
        
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Apple");
list.add("Banana");
list.add("Peach");
        
list.forEach( (obj) -> { // Outer lambda expression
    String var3; //This is declared inside of outerloop but outside of inner loop
    list.forEach( (obj2) -> { // Inner lambda expression
        var1="With null initialization"; // giving error
        var2="Without initialization"; // giving error
        var3="var3"; // giving error
    });
});
```

So firstly, how can I remove this error and also declare the variable outside of the lambda expressions?

**Secondly:**
About `var3`, when I remove the declaration of `var1` and `var2`, the error from `var3` disappears which is really strange to me. Why is it giving error when `var1` and `var2` is declared outside of the scope. How possibly `var3` is linked with `var1` and `var2`.

```java
//String var1=null;
//String var2;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Apple");
list.add("Banana");
list.add("Peach");

list.forEach( (obj) -> { // Outer lambda expression
String var3; //This is declared inside of outerloop but outside of inner loop
    list.forEach( (obj2) -> { // Inner lambda expression
        var3="var3"; // error is gone when var1 and var2 declaration is removed
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 stream variable used in lambda should be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238974/java-8-stream-variable-used-in-lambda-should-be-final-or-effectively-final)

Comment: When you say "I am getting exception" do you mean you are getting a compilation error? Exceptions and compiler errors are two completely different things.

Comment: Yes I am getting Compilation exception. I am sorry to be confusing

Comment: For the first problem, I understand that there are several solutions there and some might be helpful as well. But for the second problem. Please tell me a reason of its occurance

Comment: Cannot reproduce the other issue, `var3` is still a compiler error.

Comment: To simply put, with only declaration of `var1` and `var2`, I am getting compilation error on `var3`. How does these two lines affecting `var3`?

Comment: var1 and var2 don't affect var3. The error on var3 is still there when you remove var1 and var2, as you can see at https://ideone.com/kdI1Pr

Comment: Ok I see that. When I was removing it the compiler was not compiling `var3` therefore the error was occurring on `var1` and `var2` as they were not declared. And I thought the error from `var3` is resolved. Sorry my bad.